# Why isn't my post retrofit request working?

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I have an app that should upload the following parameters

[image]

[image]

and here I have my code

```
 @POST("task")
Call<ResponsetTask> API_Task(@Header("Authorization") String key, @Body RequestBody body);
```

[[image][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUD97.png)

and

```
 private void Analizar()  {
    File file=new File(path);



    RequestBody requestBody =RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpg"),file);
    MultipartBody.Builder builder = new MultipartBody.Builder();
    builder.setType(MultipartBody.FORM);

    builder.addFormDataPart("message", Constantes.MESSAGE);
    builder.addFormDataPart("filecomment", Constantes.FILECOMMENT);
    builder.addFormDataPart("api_token", Constantes.api_token);
    builder.addFormDataPart("user_id", Integer.toString(Constantes.id));
    builder.addFormDataPart("image","image.jpg",requestBody);

    MultipartBody body = builder.build();

    Call<ResponsetTask>call=conexion2.API_Task(Constantes.AUTH,body);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponsetTask>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponsetTask> call, Response<ResponsetTask> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                Constantes.api_task=response.body().getTaskId();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponsetTask> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });


}
```

[image]

The problem is that the post does not work and does not tell me why I have a breakpoint in my code the BodyRequest is built but when it comes to the call it simply jumps to the end that is to say the onResponse () and the onFailure () skip the code seems work and the app does not hang or give Exception

I appreciate any help friends

Answer (score 1):

This issue is that you are trying to pass data with multipart, Its an easy fix
Add this library

```
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:$retrofit_version"
```

and this convertor factory

`.addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())` in your retrofit builder 
.sample code is given below

```
    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(httpClient.build())
            .build();
```

Comment: Hello friend, sorry but I am getting an error in this line .client (httpClient.build ()) specifically the httpClient I have to add an import or something, and sorry but I am learning from this. thanks for your time

Comment: No probs bro, we all gone through this stage of learning . can i have to retrofit client class code or just add `.addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())` near to `.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())`

Comment: Hello friend, sorry for the delay but I got away from this project a bit, I tried what you are telling me but I still have the problem when I make the call.enqueue ... the logic does not go through the OnResponse () or the OnFailure it goes to the end of the method as if that part were invisible.